# SmartCard logon - Invalid Signature - on switch user

Tags: windows-7, smartcard

Little Background: I am replacing some computers in my enterprise environment. We are running Win 7 x64 Enterprise. For our SmartCard readers are are using HID OmniKey 3121. SmartCard logon worked flawlessly before. Out of 40 computers in the batch, only 2 are having issues.

Problem:
When the computer boots, userA is able to log on with smartcard without a problem. If userA logs out or hits switch users, when userB logos, they receive "the credentials cannot be verified" general message. Problem temporarily resolves itself when the computer is restarted.
Looking at the event log, it shows

```
    An error occurred while signing a message using the inserted smart card: Invalid Signature.


+ System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Smart Card Logon 

  - EventID 7 

   [ Qualifiers]  1 

   Level 2 

   Task 0 

   Keywords 0x80000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2017-01-25T18:10:49.000000000Z 

   EventRecordID 12517 

   Channel Application 

   Computer computername.xxx.xxx.net 

   Security 


- EventData 

   Invalid Signature.  
   06000980 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Binary data:


In Words

0000: 80090006    


In Bytes

0000: 06 00 09 80               ...
```

Pretty generic. I know. However, the invalid signature is the key.

I have tried new drivers, different readers, all the normal junk, but it consistently happens no matter what.

If i run cmd and use certutil /scinfo, all details populate and I have no issue. So i have narrowed the problem down to the logon event.

Any ideas to what else could be causing the error on logon?

---

commenter requested this:
No 3rd party software is being used (activClient).
Yes. tried different usb ports. as you can see in the post i tried different readers.

I dont really see how that would affect the actual process of how windows handles the
 card for logon.. but its there.

Comment: no software is being used as native support exists and we have found ActivClient to be more of a headache and causes more issues than it fixed. Applied a new image?? Why would i want to do that? Ya, that will take me 5 minutes but my question is does anyone have any ideas causing the error. in the OP i already stated i tried different readers, and ya, of course i tried different drivers. I aint no newb. I had this problem last year with a new batch and HID was no help. I spent 2 hours on the phone trying to get a human.. and if you dont have a support contract your SOL.

Comment: really!?? are you saying windows doesn't have native support on Win 7?? thta funny since my 4000+ computers have been able to use a smart card without any 3rd party software for the last 3 years when we ditched the activClient software.

Comment: I am indeed saying that.  I wish you good luck.  Windows has native support for the smart cards themselfs, but in my personal experience, in order to use the certificate on the card itself in order to authenticate the windows session that required a client like ActivClient.

Comment: I am really going to regret this based on your 'reaction" to my statement.  I just wanted to confirm that, the same user(s) that report this problem as happening on those 2 machines, can repeat the steps that reproduce the behavior you describe on the other 38 machines, and are unable to reproduce the behavior?  *When you get around applying your image to these 2 machines update your question.*

Answer (score 0):

User Profile Service leaked handles seemed to be the problem being caused by NVIDIA causing a 610 error on the card as the service wasnt able to get access to the registry item. Updated video driver. all is well.